# SetText row by row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-dialog

Am trying to set the `TextView` to read my number results coming from an algorithm. I want to sort them row by row. The numbers are now showing one beside each other. How can I can make them row by row?
I made new custom dialog that has this `TextView` called Peak_num but I can't go further and sort them. I hope someone can help me.

```
 List<Integer> List_Of_Peaks = findPeaks(String_TO_List);
 dialog.setTitle("my Dialog");
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
 dialog.show();
 Log.i(TAG, "Peaks" + List_Of_Peaks);   
 Peaks_num = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Peak_Num);
 Peaks_num.setText(String.valueOf(List_Of_Peaks));


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Peak_Num"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:text="Peaks"
        android:textColor="#040307"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

[image: This is how the dialog looks like, and I wanted them to be in row by row]

Comment: your question does not make any sense could you please provide an image to better clear your question

Comment: Look into ListView maybe?

Comment: **List_of_Peaks** has string of numbers and I want to set them row by row. setText can't provide this feature I assumed. However it did have **.split** method. I hope now you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<Integer> List_Of_Peaks = findPeaks(String_TO_List);
 dialog.setTitle("my Dialog");
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
 dialog.show();
 Log.i(TAG, "Peaks" + List_Of_Peaks);   
 Peaks_num = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Peak_Num);
 String text="";
 for(Integer integer:List_Of_Peaks)
 {
      text+=integer+"\n"; // split
 }
 Peaks_num.setText(text);
```

Comment: Yes, that is what am looking for. Thanks a lot.